# limit of $f(x)g(x)$ as $x\to0$ where $f(x)\to\infty$ and $g(x)\to-\infty$

Tags: analysis

I have come to ask a question about  question in a textbook of mine. The book states that there exist $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=-\infty$, but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)\to0$. This seems impossible to me. I just want to make sure my logic is correct, or if I am horribly misunderstanding something.

Let $P>0$. Supposing $f,g\to\infty,-\infty$, respectively, as $x\to0$, then there exist $\delta_f,\delta_g>0$ such that $x_f\in(-\delta_f,\delta_f)$ and $x_g\in(-\delta_g,\delta_g)$ implies $f(x_f)>\sqrt{P}$ and $g(x_f)<-\sqrt{P}$. Setting $\delta=\min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$, and supposing $-\delta<x<\delta$, we find $f(x)>\sqrt{P}$ and $g(x)<-\sqrt{P}$. It follows that $f(x)g(x)<-P$, therefore $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Your book's claim (assuming you are quoting it correctly) is false.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, but I've to doubt my intuition, so I wanted a second opinion. This isn't the first mistake the book has made.

Comment: Is a $+$ sign missing between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?  That would be a simple printing mistake.

Comment: I think you might be right. Though, if that's the case it appears the author left it out four times, because of other claims they make in the same problem, but I guess that understandable if they used copy and paste.